# How to extract text from textview, resourceId is known in python

Tags: python, android-uiautomator

How can i extract text or save it, from TextView when resourceId is known. currently am taking screenshot and using tesseract to extract text out of the image. but it takes lot of time and sometimes does mistakes as well. If am able to get text from resourceId then would save some time. have seen threads to do so with java, but want to use it in Python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to use python to get the text of a TextView knowing its resource id (*in the example I'm using the id for the date widget*):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

res = "com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/clock"
print(ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()).findViewByIdOrRaise(res).getText())
```

##### edit

The error you mentioned:

```
ValueError: received does not contain valid XML: Killed
```

is, unfortunately, a limitation of the UiAutomator backend. However, **AndroidViewClient/culebra** can choose a different backend in this an other situations.

You can follow the steps described at [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) and a few simple changes to the above script to account for some differences in the API (notice `useuiautomatorhelper=True`):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

res = "com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/clock"
vc = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(), useuiautomatorhelper=True)
print(vc.uiAutomatorHelper.ui_object2.get_text(vc.findViewByIdOrRaise(res).oid).text)
```

Comment: it worked successfully, but only once now it shows error: "ValueError: received does not contain valid XML: Killed". have tried after restart again, same error. what must be the problem?

Comment: after doing all mentioned above get error as follows.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/jaypatel/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/com/dtmilano/android/uiautomator/uiautomatorhelper.py", line 504, in get_text
return self.uiAutomatorHelper.api_instance.ui_object2_get_text_get(oid=oid)
AttributeError: 'DefaultApi' object has no attribute 'ui_object2_get_text_get'

Comment: also how do i start-server within from the code?

Comment: Be sure you are on the latest version of AndroidViewClient v20.6.2. To start the server you can run `bash <(curl -sL https://git.io/JT5nc) start-server`

Comment: after starting server UIAUTOMATOR gets disconnected. and not able to connect back. am able to extract text using the commands suggested by you, it works great but after that not able to connect to UIAUTOMATOR again for further commands. have tried using your examples to 'vc.findViewByText("example").click()' and various others, but no success. please help.please refer to my code example in one of my answers as reference for better understanding(if it helps). thanks again.

Comment: They are mutually exclusive. You have to kill the server if you want to return to UiAutomator. However, most of the commands have an equivalent, as close as the original one as possible. Feel free to ask more questions if you are dealing with issues due to the migration of the backend.

Comment: [calculator-wait-uiautomator-helper](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/calculator-wait-uiautomator-helper) has an example of finding objects by text that may help you

Comment: Remember you can use [this](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/wiki/Using-mrin9) to explore the new API

Comment: Have tried almost everything from above(mentioned by you and other from google as well). what i found was In case UIautomator:  device(text="Example1").click() works, and in case of AndroidViewClient vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise("Example1").touch() worked as well, but Example2 works with UIautomator, and errors out as: Couldn't find View with text='Example2' in tree with root=ROOT, Also tried it with resourdeID, same error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, using Uiautomator is as simple, but it took me so long to figure it out.

```
text = device(resourceId="your resourceId").get_text()`
```